# Python import variable from file

Tags: python-2.7, import

i have a this 2 file: main.py and abc.py

main.py is:

```
dm = [100, 200, 300]
import abc
abc.abcp(dm)
from abc import *
pabc = abc.dmabc
print pabc
```

abc.py is:

```
def abcp(dm):
    dmabc = list(dm)
    dmabc[0] -= 50
    print dmabc
    return dmabc
```

The error is: pabc = abc.dmabc (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute dmabc)

if i write:

```
from abc import abcp
pabc = abc.dmabc
print pabc
```

The error is: from abc import abcp (ImportError: cannot import name bmf)

if i write:

```
from abc import abcp
from abcp import dmabc
pabc = abc.dmabc
print pabc
```

The error is: from abpc import dmabc (ImportError: No module named abpc)

So how can i import dmabc variable from abc.py file?

Comment: `dmabc` *only exists inside `abcp`*, so you can't access it from other modules. If you need to, do something like `pabc = abc.abcp(dm)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the variable `dmabc` because it's a local variable in `abc.py`.

The best way would be to **store the return value** when calling `abc.dmabc`:

`main.py`:

```
dm = [100, 200, 300]
import abc
pabc = abc.abcp(dm)
print pabc
```

Comment: So i have to print in that file instead try to import variable?

Comment: You can also print it inside `abc.py`, but the only way to access it in `main.py` would be to store the return value of the method. So, printing works in both modules but importing does not work since it's a local variable that only exists in `abc.py` and you cannot access it from `main.py`.